# solving for probability given odds

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

In the case of flipping a coin, I understand intuitively that $$d = \frac{p}{1 - p}$$ where $p$ is the probability of flipping heads and $d$ is the odds of flipping heads. I am given that:

$$p = \frac{d}{1 + d}$$

How is the algebra done that allows me to solve for $p$ given the equation for $d$? Or, how else would I come to the conclusion that in the case of flipping a coin:

$$p = \frac{d}{1 + d}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between "the probability of flipping heads" and "the odds of flipping heads."  Can you elaborate on how these are different?

Comment: Certainly. My understanding is that the probability of an event is the number of possibilities that result in an event divided by the total number of possibilities. If a coin is fair the P(heads) = 1/2. The odds are the ratio of the number of possibilities that result in an event to the number of possibilities that don't result in the event. if a coin is fair D(heads) = 1/1 or 1:1.

Comment: A fair coin toss has an odds for heads of "one to one." It's most often used in gambling, because it represents the payoff. If the odds are "3:1", then if you and I bet, and I bet in favor of the event, you should win 3 times what I would win for the bet to be fair. @abiessu

Comment: That said, often mathematicians use "odds" and "probability" interchangeably, because gambler "odds" add no useful information.

Comment: Odds of event $E$ are $\frac{p E}{p E^C}$, odds against event $E$ are odds of event $E^c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the algebra, notice that we have

$$d=\frac p{1-p}\\
d(1-p)=p\\
d=p+pd\\
p=\frac d{d+1}$$

This algebraic manipulation works in either direction, assuming both $1-p\neq 0$ and $d+1\neq 0$.